# How to fix Windows App certification kit Platform version launch failure

Tags: windows, uwp, publish, xamarin.uwp

I am trying to prepare my Windows application for deployment and I used the Windows App certification kit tool to run tests on it. I get the error in the image attached, the documentation in the link is useless. I am using Xamarin to build my application, any ideas on how I can fix this?[image]

Comment: If you are running the local WACK test, you could try to upload it to the store and take the result of the online WACK test as standard.

Comment: I am using the local WACK test, according to the docs, I understand that it should pass this first before going to the store

Comment: There might be some unexpected errors in the local tests due to different reasons for the local device. The online WACK test will run no matter you run the local test or not. The online WACK test is more accurate and the store only check the online test result.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Worked when I uploaded it, thanks. :) .... Maybe make this an answer so that I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Sure, I'll write an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the local WACK test, you could try to upload it to the store and take the result of the online WACK test as standard. Because there might be some unexpected errors in the local tests due to different reasons for the local device. The online WACK test will run no matter you run the local test or not. The online WACK test is more accurate and the store only checks the online test result.